How can I set RAM limit to force using swap?
I have a few benchmarks to run, which concern using swap instead of RAM. The "problem" is that I have 32 GB RAM, and I need to simulate having 8 GB and large swap memory. So I want to limit the actual RAM used, but not the swap - processes are allowed to use as much of it as they need.
How can I do this? For a single process or system-wide, both are fine.
I am using Ubuntu 24.04, and benchmarks run using Python (specifically IPython in Jupyter Notebook).

Try adding to the kernel boot line (edit the grub boot stanza) e.g. :
mem=8500M on the kernel boot line to restrict memory to 8G
